# JPQL query to return items with at least one category belonging to a list of categories

Tags: jpa, derby, jpql

I want to make a query similar to the following jpql query:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.category IN :categories
```

This query returns items with category belonging to the passed :categories list.
But the query I need needs to be something like this:

```
//This JPQL Query does not work (and is only used to explain the problem)
SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.categoryList IN :categories
```

Note: The biggest difference from the previous query is that this time items has a list of categories.

This query will return any item that has at leasy one of its category belonging to the :categories list.

I have read this page: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/index.htm. But I can't seem to think of a proper way to do it.

My current options are doing a native SQL query (which isn't as elegant as a JPQL and not as efficient) and getting all the items list and filtering it with Java Code (which is probably what I will do in worst case scenario).

Thank you!

Comment: You need to learn about joins. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. `select i from Item i join i.categoryList category where category in :categories`. Use the singular form for your entties: an instance of Items is an Item, so the class should be named Item, not Items. Just like the class String is named String, not Strings.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to learn about joins. "Items" was actually a typo in the second query.